# Keep highest flat rate shipping cost and local pickup in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm trying to show the highest shipping costs in the cart. I've found a nice little snippet for that:

```
function only_show_most_expensive_shipping_rate( $rates, $package ) {
    $most_expensive_method = '';
    $new_rates = array();
    // Loop through shipping rates
    if ( is_array( $rates ) ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $key => $rate ) {   
         // Set variables when the rate is more expensive than the one saved
         if ( empty( $most_expensive_method ) || $rate->cost > $most_expensive_method->cost ){
            $most_expensive_method = $rate;
         }

        }
    }
    // Return the most expensive rate when possible
    if ( ! empty( $most_expensive_method ) ){
       /**  
        ** Keep local pickup if it's present.
        **/
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ('local_pickup' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $new_rates[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                break;
            }
        }
        return array( $most_expensive_method->id => $most_expensive_method );
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_action('woocommerce_package_rates', 'only_show_most_expensive_shipping_rate', 10, 2);
```

However this snippet also hides the "local pickup" shipping method.

Why does the above method doesn't work? Right now it only shows the highest shipping class/price and hide all others including the pickup method.

Is it because of the two arrays? I don't see any errors popping up.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will keep the highest shipping Flat rate cost and the Local pickup shipping method:

```
add_action('woocommerce_package_rates', 'keep_highest_flat_rate_cost', 10, 2);
function keep_highest_flat_rate_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    $flat_rate_costs = [];

    // Loop through shipping methods rates
    foreach ( $rates as $key_rate => $rate ) {
        // Targeting only "Flat rate" type shipping methods
        if ( ! in_array( $rate->method_id, ['local_pickup', 'free_shipping'] ) ) {
            // Store the Rate ID keys with corresponding costs in an indexed array
            $flat_rate_costs[$key_rate] = $rate->cost;
        }
    }
    // Sorting "Flat rate" costs in DESC order
    arsort($flat_rate_costs);

    // Remove the highest cost from the array
    array_shift($flat_rate_costs);

    // Loop through remaining "Flat rate" shipping methods to remove them all
    foreach ( $flat_rate_costs as $key_rate => $cost){
        unset($rates[$key_rate]);
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **You should need to refresh the shipping caches:** 
>   1) First ensure that the code is already saved on your function.php file. 
>   2) In Shipping settings, enter in a Shipping Zone: Disable any **Shipping Method** and "save", then re-enable it and "save". **You are done.**

Comment: Well that works perfectly! Thank you. Since I'm learning PHP also thanks for your comments on what does what. Never thought of sorting while this could be a method in javascript which I know better.

Comment: Hi How i can show cheapest shipping rate and local pick up same time ??